# inserting colors using css on my javascript buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put CSS design to my code. green on the parent button and yellow on the child button. the main button only lights green when i click the child in it.

```html
<button id="btn_rv" onclick="myFunction(this)" data-counter="1">Main Button</button>
<script>
function myFunction(btn) {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  btn.style.background='green';
  var counter = parseInt(btn.getAttribute('data-counter'));
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = btn.id + '_' + counter;
  button.id = btn.id + '_' + counter;
  button.setAttribute('data-counter', '1');
  button.setAttribute('onclick','myFunction(this)');
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  btn.setAttribute('data-counter', ++counter);
  button.style.background='yellow';
}
</script>
```

Comment: remove that line: **btn.className = "parent";**

Comment: @ymz it will not work sir

Comment: won;t work is a bad description of a problem + your code snippet does not work.. please fix it and describe the problem :)

Comment: sir sorry, i dont know whats the problem with the snippet but the codes works in my browser. im using sublime as text editor

Comment: try to upload to jsFiddle AND POST THE LINK HERE (inside the comment section)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uo9gfy1x/ sir still not working even in jsfiddle sorry its my first time in programming

Comment: sir it does work in html! :)

Comment: sir i already edit the above code

Comment: @Christian What is not working. You want https://jsfiddle.net/uo9gfy1x/1/ ?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/tjuc2q82 sir it must be like this, but all the green buttons are connected to the parents and grandparents and so on, the yellow button connects to all the child and grandchild and so on

Comment: @Christian https://jsfiddle.net/uo9gfy1x/2/ What what is meaning connected? What is your expected output exactly?

Comment: sir the meaning of connected is when i click the mainbutton it creates a child button named btn_rv_1 so they connect. the parent button of btn_rv_1 is main button and the child of main button is btn_rv_1

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a language barrier issue (keep practicing!), not being able to properly explain what your problem is - here's a checklist to keep in mind for future questions:

- [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (✕ - failed to convey your problem )
- [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)            (✓ - you did provide some code of your own)

Having some spare time, I took a stab at what I *think* you were asking for.
All element styling is defined (as it should, when possible) in the css. Made some helpful comments in case it's confusing. Good luck!

---

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6z1jpqx7/) | Snippet below

```js
// Get element references - once
var btnMain = document.getElementById("btnMain"),
    ulRoot = document.getElementById("ulChildren");

var DEPTH_MAX = 4;

// Event handler function
function click_CreateChild() {
  var parent = this.parentNode,
      children = parent.childNodes,
      list = null;

  // Count node depth
  var current = parent,
      depth = 0;
  while (current != ulRoot) {
    if (current.nodeName === "UL")
      depth++;
    current = current.parentNode;
  }

  // Add a depth constraint maybe?
  if (depth >= DEPTH_MAX)
    return;

  // Find the ul element
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
    if (children[i].nodeName == "UL")
      list = children[i];

  // Create a ul element if none was found
  if (list === null) {
    list = document.createElement("ul");
    parent.appendChild(list);
  }

  // Add the child node to the list
  var li = document.createElement("li"),
      btn = document.createElement("button");

  // Give the button a name and a click event handler. First number is depth, the second is the child's index
  btn.innerHTML = "Node " + (depth + 1) + " - " + (list.childNodes.length + 1);
  btn.onclick = click_CreateChild;

  // Add it to the DOM
  li.appendChild(btn);
  list.appendChild(li);
}

// Add the event handler to the main button
btnMain.onclick = click_CreateChild;
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li > ul {
  margin: 0.33em 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
}

ul li {
  padding-left: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
}

/* Add some colors based on depth. The last defined depth color definition will be inherited to any children beyond that */
ul button { background-color: #c0392b; }
ul ul button { background-color: #f39c12; }
ul ul ul button { background-color: #28b363; }
ul ul ul ul button { background-color: #2981ba; }
ul ul ul ul ul button {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
/* and so on.. */
```

```html
<ul id="ulChildren">
  <li>
    <button id="btnMain">Root</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```